# Number of currently logged users to the community

Tags: apex, soql, community, sosl

I trying display number of currently logged users to the community in my lightning component. 
Now I using below SOQL query:

```
List<AggregateResult> numberCurrentlyLogged = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(LoginHistory.UserId) number FROM AuthSession WHERE LoginType = 'Application' AND SessionType = 'UI'];
```

this query return count of all currently logged user to ORG not to community.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue base on AuthSession - user type and sesion. 
Added single permset to acces in community - so I need add it to the user. 
I put all user with PermSet to the Set and loop for agregate resoult from authSesion LoginHistory.UserId. And If in Set and in AuuthSession add 1 to the counter.

Answer (score 4):

Add this (or similar - you may have to query and check for a value corresponding to your community):

```
UserType = 'Customer Portal User'
```

From [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm):

> UserType
>
> **Type**
>   picklist
>
> **Properties**
>   Filter, Group, Restricted picklist, Sort
>
> **Description**
>   The kind of user for this session. Types include Standard, Partner, Customer Portal Manager, High Volume Portal, and CSN Only.

Comment: This is a part : )  I have 3 communities and I need display on it inform how many users are currently logged to this community.  For example I have 
 2 communities A and B on A logged 5 user and display 5 but on B logged 3 and display 3 ; )